# Добавление элемента в начало массива json

Tags: javascript, json

Столкнулся с такой проблемой! Добавление элемента в начало массива.
Порядок действий я пронумеровал, а код выложил [тут](http://codepen.io/Brave_Lime/pen/PzzwXm?editors=0010).
Массив называется Returned_Json . Суть проста. Добавление комментариев в localStorage.
Буду очень благодарен!

Еще раз ссылка (http://codepen.io/Brave_Lime/pen/PzzwXm?editors=0010)

Вот основной кусок:

```js
function main_json(a){
    if(a==0){ //6
        localStorage.setItem('LocalStorage', Returned_Json); //Здесь Обновиться localStorage
    console.log(localStorage.LocalStorage);
    }
    else { // 3
        Returned_Json = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('LocalStorage'));//Здесь он создается
    console.log(Returned_Json);
        return Returned_Json;
    }
};

function post_comment() {  //2
    $.each(main_json().posts, function(i, post){         //7
        var list='<div>';
        ...
        list+='</div>';
        $("#Main_Content_Comment").append(list);
    }); 
};

function post() {  //4
    main_json().posts.unshift( //**//Здесь должен изменяться - Основная проблема! Не добавляется в массив.
        {
            "time": '10',
        });
    var a=0;
    console.log(main_json().posts);
    console.log(Returned_Json);
    console.log(localStorage.LocalStorage);
    main_json(a); //5
    post_comment(); 
};
$(document).ready(function() {
  post_comment();
});
```

Проблема: в `main_json().posts` (по сути это и есть массив `Returned_Json`) не добавляется указанный элемент. Что ступорит дальнейшее выполнение...

Comment: без содержания `main_json` вопрос слишком широк, как и без `post_comment`. Кроме того еще в прошлом вопросе определились, что надо просто записать _измененный_ массив обратно в localStorage

Comment: @Grundy я выложил весь код. (http://codepen.io/Brave_Lime/pen/PzzwXm?editors=0011)

Comment: **необходимый** код должен быть **непосредственно** в вопросе, ссылки могут быть только дополнением. Кроме того почитайте как создать [mcve]

Comment: кроме того, по ссылке слишком много лишнего текста, и в них теряются эти пункты, в итоге: куча кода, который непонятно что делает, и непонятно в какой части проблема

Comment: Ага, теперь осталось только сформулировать проблему: что именно происходит не так? Присутствуют ли ошибки в консоли? Ничего не происходит? Какое-то неожиданное поведение?

Comment: Мне кажется, Вы не задали вопрос.

Comment: @Brave_Lime, почему вы решили, что в месте, которое вы отметили в комментарии массив не меняется?

Comment: @Grundy если через `consol.log()` вывести `main_json().posts` or `Returned_Json` or `localStorage.LocalStorage` , то там как было два элемента, так и остается!

Comment: добавьте код которым пытались проверить так же в пример, и еще стоит описать что нужно сделать, чтобы вызвать этот метод `post`. Я ни одного вызова не нашел

Comment: также стоит **выкинуть из примера** все **лишнее**, чтобы он стал [mcve] сейчас в нем слишком много постороннего и ненужного кода

Comment: Ну вот :-) теперь все ясно :-) вызов `main_json()` в первом консоль логе, перетирает значение `Returned_Json` - и следующие выводят уже старое значение :-)

Comment: @Grundy Подскажите, почему ,тогда, при выводе `console.log(localStorage);` ответ `"[object Object]"` ... потому-то `post_comment` и не понимает его... Наверное :(

Comment: @Brave_Lime, не вижу этой строки, а, хотя понял: так как `localStorage` хранит только строки, объект приводится к строке автоматически и получает следующую строку: _"[object Object]"_ которая и сохраняется. Записывать надо по аналогии с чтением, используя объект `JSON`, конкретнее метод: `stringify`

Comment: @Grundy ,а можно где-то лайк поставить? :) Спасибо огромное!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Как выяснилось из комментариев основная проблема была в неверном обновлении данных в `localStorage`

```
localStorage.setItem('LocalStorage', Returned_Json); //Здесь Обновиться localStorage
```

[`localStorage`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Storage_API/Using_the_Web_Storage_API) позволяет хранить **только** строки, поэтому в данном случае объект `Returned_Json` будет приведен в строку, обычно *"[object Object]"* и уже это значение будет записано.

Для исправления ситуации стоит использовать [метод `stringify` объекта JSON](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify), который как раз и переводит объект в строку в виде JSON.

Таким образом данная строка должна выглядеть так:

```
localStorage.setItem('LocalStorage', JSON.stringify(Returned_Json)); //Здесь Обновиться localStorage
```